# How to connect to mosh-server with ipv6 address using juicessh?

Tags: ipv6, mosh

I've been trying to connect to my computer running a mosh-server via juicessh by way of ipv6. Everything starts up ok, it connects, then asks for a password. Then after that juicessh (mosh-client) fails, it comes back with "bad ip address" and diconnects.

The address is a local ipv6 address of form fe80::abcd:1234:5678:90ef%wlan0. Thank you for your help. Bty, ssh using juicessh to ipv6 address works fine.

Answer (score 1):

The `%wlan` portion references the particular network adapter on your computer. That portion of the address might be required if you are configuring a listening port on your computer, configuring routing rules, etc. But remote systems do not see that.

Type only the following into the address box on JuiceSSH `fe80::abcd:1234:5678:90ef`

As an additional note, JuiceSSH doesn't but other tools might require you wrap an IPv6 address in square brackets such as `wget http://[fe80::abcd:1234:5678:90ef]:8080`.

The [IPv6 Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6_address) is a good reference for this information.